# Symfony too many redirects

Tags: php, symfony, redirect, firewall

After many tests, I still have a redirection problem with my Symfony project (online, production mode).
When I clean the cache, il works for a few hours, or a few days, and then.... 'that the page has made too many redirects'

I'm using fosuserBundle and jmsSecurityExtraBundle. I tried many modifications in my security.yml, but nothing worked..

Please.... help....

Here is my security.yml :

```
jms_security_extra:
    secure_all_services: false
    expressions: true

security:
    encoders:
        Rezofresh\UserBundle\Entity\User: sha512

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       [ROLE_USER, ROLE_COMPANY]
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

    providers:
        main:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username_email
        custom:
            id: rezofresh_user.my_provider

    firewalls:
        #dev:
            #pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            #security: false
            #anonymous: ~

        # On crée un pare-feu uniquement pour le formulaire
        #main_login:
            # Cette expression régulière permet de prendre /login (mais pas /login_check !)
            #pattern:   ^/login$
            #anonymous: ~
            #anonymous: true # On autorise alors les anonymes sur ce pare-feu

        main:
            pattern:        ^/
            anonymous: ~
            #anonymous:      true
            provider:       custom
            form_login:
                #login_path: fos_user_security_login
                login_path: /
                use_forward: false
                check_path: fos_user_security_check
                default_target_path: rezofreshrezo_locale
                failure_path: null
                remember_me: true
            logout:
                path:       fos_user_security_logout
                target:     /
            remember_me:
                key:      "%secret%"
                lifetime: 31536000 # 365 jours en secondes
                path:     /
                domain:   ~ # Prend la valeur par défaut du domaine courant depuis $_SERVER

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/%locale%/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/%locale%/user, roles: ROLE_USER }
        - { path: ^/%locale%/company, roles: ROLE_COMPANY }
        - { path: ^/%locale%/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

Comment: I don't know who would upvote because you have provided little information to help solve your problem. Which route(s) are causing the redirects, what cache layer are you using?

Comment: Which page ? A login one ?

Comment: When the problem occurs, any page of the site is accessible, for anybody (login page wich is the home page, user personnal space page, ...) .. So, I have no idea of the responsible route.
I have nothing set the cache system, is there different ways to configure it ?